# scrollLeft() works too slow

Tags: jquery, scroll

I need to make a small fixed button "to the top" at the bottom of my page. Since I need it to be relative to one of the containers on my page I am trying to calculate coordinates with the help of jquery. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var button = $('.button-up');    
    var left = parseInt(button.css('left'));

    $(window).scroll(function(event) {   

        if ($(window).scrollLeft() > 0){   
            var scroll = $(this).scrollLeft();                
            var leftNew = left - scroll;                
            console.log('scrollleft:', scroll, ' left: ', left, ' left\':', leftNew);                
            button.css('left', leftNew + "px");
        }  
    });
});
```

It works when I move scrollbar slowly. But when I do it quickly scrollLeft() is not recalculated properly. So a situation when bar is on the left side and console.log says that it is 50px is possible. When it happens my button goes left and covers the content area. Can I prevent this effect somehow?
I tried to use scrollX from JS and change $(this) to window, but it has the same effect